# using Retrofit 2.2.0 on mobile device the activity disappeared

Tags: android, mobile, retrofit2

I am new to Retrofit library. when I run Register Activity as you can see below on my mobile app debugging the activity disappears after I click Signup button

```
         public class RetrofitFishFarmApi {
private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
// main client
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
private static final String BASE_API_URL = "http://192.168.43.1:3000/";
// Retrofit
private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return createService(serviceClass, null);
}


public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass,
                                  final String authToken) {
    // IMP: always clear the interceptors.
    if (authToken != null && !authToken.equals("")) {
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                // Request customization: add request headers
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header(AUTHORIZATION, authToken)
                        .method(original.method(), original.body());

                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
    }

    // build the Retrofit instance with the Token Authorization OkHttpClient.
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();

    // return the ServiceClass passed.
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

And the register Activity is as below

```
 public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button txtRegister;
private TextInputLayout inputFullName;
private TextInputLayout inputEmail;
private TextInputLayout inputPassword;
private TextInputLayout inputPasswordRepeat;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private TextInputLayout inputPhone;
private TextInputLayout inputUsername;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);

    inputFullName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.register_full_name);
    inputEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
    inputUsername = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.register_username);
    inputPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
    inputPasswordRepeat = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.register_pass_rep);
    inputPhone = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.register_phone);
    txtRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_btn);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    txtRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            onRegister(inputFullName, inputEmail,inputUsername,
                    inputPassword, inputPasswordRepeat,inputPhone);
        }
    });
}

public void onRegister(TextInputLayout inputFullName,
                       TextInputLayout inputEmail,
                       TextInputLayout inputUsername,
                       TextInputLayout inputPassword,
                       TextInputLayout inputPasswordRepeat,
                       TextInputLayout inputPhone) {

    String fullName = inputFullName.getEditText().getText().toString();
    if (fullName.isEmpty()) {
        inputFullName.setError("User name can't be empty");
        return;
    }
    inputFullName.setError("");

    String email = inputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        inputEmail.setError("User name can't be empty");
        return;
    }
    inputEmail.setError("");

    String username = inputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
    if (username.isEmpty()) {
        inputUsername.setError("User name can't be empty");
        return;
    }
    inputUsername.setError("");

    String pass = inputPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
    if (pass.isEmpty()) {
        inputPassword.setError("Password can't be empty");
        return;
    }
    inputPassword.setError("");

    String passRep = inputPasswordRepeat.getEditText().getText().toString();
    if (!pass.equals(passRep)) {
        inputPasswordRepeat.setError("Passwords are different");
        return;
    }
    inputPasswordRepeat.setError("");

    String phone = inputPhone.getEditText().getText().toString();
    if (phone.isEmpty()) {
        inputPhone.setError("Password can't be empty");
        return;
    }
    inputPhone.setError("");

    UserService userService = RetrofitFishFarmApi.createService(UserService.class);
    User userEntity = new User();

    userEntity.setFull_name(fullName);
    userEntity.setEmail(email);
    userEntity.setUsername(username);
    userEntity.setPassword(pass);
    userEntity.setPhone(phone);



  Call<User> callUserApi = userService.login(userEntity);

    callUserApi.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call,
                               Response<User> response) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Message fro server"+response.body().getFull_name(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call,
                              Throwable throwable) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No connection service",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


        }
    });


    //Snackbar.make(, "Register success!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

}

And the my Pojo User is

package fishfarm.gebeya.fishfarm.model;

```
 import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
```

/**
 * Created by Gere on 4/30/2017.
 */

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("user_id")
@Expose
private String user_id;

@SerializedName("full_name")
@Expose
private String full_name;

@SerializedName("accessToken")
@Expose
private String accessToken;

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;

@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;

@SerializedName("created_at")
@Expose
private String created_at;

@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private  String password;

@SerializedName("admin")
@Expose
private  boolean admin;


public String getFull_name() {
    return full_name;
}

public void setFull_name(String full_name) {
    this.full_name = full_name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public boolean isAdmin() {
    return admin;
}

public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
    this.admin = admin;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}

public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}
```

}

Thank you for helping!

Comment: What error your getting in log.

Comment: Did you add the internet permission to your manifest?

Comment: Yes I already added it. why is not showing some errors?? why is the activity disappread

Comment: Look for `finish()` statements in your code and if they are being hit

Comment: @JordyLangen commenting at the finish can not fix it. I think the problem is when  register button is click after sanity check the activity gone away